# NoReverseMatch with keyword argument uidb64 with Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-2.0

I can't understand why my code doesn't work. Before it worked, but now, when I run the server and test, the code does not work.

When the user is registering, I send him activation email, like this:

```
def send_activation_email(serializer, request, user):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
        'user': user,
        'domain': current_site.domain,
        'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
        'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
    })
    mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
    to_email = serializer.data['email']

    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
    email.send()
```

**acc_active_email.html**

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and my url file

```
.
.
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate_account, name='activate'),
.
.
```

but I have this error:

```
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': b'NDM', 'token': '4qz-8f770502bd8b02786da9'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

highlights this line `http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}`

Comment: I wonder whether it's not working because `uid` is bytes. Try hardcoding `'uid': 'NDM'` to see whether it fixes the error.

Comment: @Alasdair wow, if i set 'uid': 'NDM' in method `send_activation_email` its work. This is strangely

Comment: OK, it looks as if you need to convert the bytes to a string to be able to reverse the url.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In Django 2.0 and 2.1 you should call `decode()` after base64 encoding the uid, to convert it to a string:

```
message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})
```

See the note in the [Django 2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#removed-support-for-bytestrings-in-some-places) for more info.

In Django 2.2+, `urlsafe_base64_encode` [returns a string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#miscellaneous), so there is no need to decode.

```
message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})
```

It should be possible to write code that is compatible with Django <= 1.11, 2.0-2.1, and 2.2+, by using `force_text`. Note the following is untested.

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text

message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
    'user': user,
    'domain': current_site.domain,
    'uid': force_text(urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk))),
    'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
})
```

You can drop the `force_text` and use the second code snippet once you drop support for Django < 2.2.

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Django, you can use the slug syntax. For example:

```py
path(
    'activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/',
    views.activate_account, 
    name='activate'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I configured my template (acc_active_email.html) to be like this:

```
{% autoescape off %}

Hello {{ name }}!

Please confirm your email by clicking on the following link.

http://{{ domain }}/activate/{{ uid }}/{{ token }}

{% endautoescape %}
```

Next I included in the urls.py from my app:

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate')
```

I don't know if it's the best way, but it solved my problems. However, I used django 4.1 version, so may be it doesn't work well for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its stupid since the URL is not dynamic but it worked...

```
path('activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer please for easier understanding.