# Registration using e-mail, Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

I'm just a beginner, so i got some questions making my first project. I've got code in views:

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        mail_subject = 'Активация'
        message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        print(message) # здесь я смотрю какое сообщение отправляю

        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
                    mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Пожалуйста, подтвердите адрес электронной почты')
else:
    form = SignupForm()
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

This code is from urls:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('activate/?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

The problem is that i always get invalid URL in my email.
I think it is about new 'path' function, which may be used is

```
<int:uidb64>
```

but not really sure. 
Thank for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use regexes like `[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+` when you use [`path()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path). If you want to use regexes, then use [`re_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path) (which works the same as `url()` from older versions of Django).

When you use `path()`, you can use one of the built-in [path converters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters). You can't use `<int:uidb64>`, because uidb can contain `A-Za-z`, hyphens, and underscores, not just digits.

For your `uidb64` and `token`, I think `slug` is the most suitable of the path converters included in Django.

```
path('activate/<slug:uidb64>/<slug:token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

This will match slugs and tokens which your regex wouldn't allow, but this isn't a problem as long as your `check_token` method returns `False` for these invalid values and does not raise an error.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but now i get NoReverseMatch at /signup/.
Can you please give an advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this is about my html file:
{% autoescape off %}
Здравствуйте {{ user.username }},
Пожалуйста нажмите на ссылку, чтобы активировать аккаунт:
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' <slug:uidb64>=uid <slug:token>=token %}
{% endautoescape %}

Comment: You don't use the path converters syntax in the url tag, just the variable name: `{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}`. Or you can use positional arguments: `{% url 'activate' uid token %}`.

Comment: Still got a error with that 'activate'.
Reverse for 'activate' with arguments '(b'NjI', '4rz-742abd4c7bd36c6edcd0')' not found. Using both of your variants, it comes much more clear to me, but i still can't get why it dont work. Do i understand right that 'activate' is supposed to be just a word inside that URL?

Comment: You use `'activate'` because you are trying to reverse the pattern with `name='activate'`. The problem is that `b'Njl'` is bytes. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177696/noreversematch-django-template-url. If you're still stuck, please ask a new question because this is a separate issue.

Comment: Appreciate your comments so much! It worked. That was all about that decode, everithing becomes so much clearer! Thank you!