# django 2 re_path expression passing email verification token

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-urls, django-2.0

I'm quite stuck with using regular expression in django 2 url.
All seems to be correct, however i'm getting `404` error.

Actual path:

```
http://localhost:8000/user/activate/b'MjQ'/4zb-89a933fe70e0d12de725/
```

error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in ec2django.urls, Django tried these URL        patterns, in this order:

user/
^user/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$ [name='activate']
health/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$

The current path, user/activate/b'MjQ'/4zb-89a933fe70e0d12de725/, didn't match any of these.
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
   .....
   re_path(r'^user/activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        user_activate, name='activate')
]
```

Generating the tokens:

```
            from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes
            from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode
            from django.template.loader import render_to_string
            from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator

            message = render_to_string('email_account_activate.html', {
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user),
            })
```

Verification:

```
try:
    uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
    user = MyUser.objects.get(pk=uid)
except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, MyUser.DoesNotExist):
    user = None
if user is not None and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
    user.is_active = True
    user.save()
```

Is the problem with the url or token format? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your url contains single quotes (`b'MjQ'`) as argument for the first pattern, wich doesn't match the regex `[0-9A-Za-z_\-]`.

Comment: so how does the uid should be transported? most of the samples i found pass the `uid` in this way

Comment: The pattern looks like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal. In this case it is python code, wich belongs to a python script, not the url rendered in the template. How do you code your urls in the templates?

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177696/noreversematch-with-keyword-argument-uidb64-with-django-2-0